# Passing a variable and reading a dataframe using input()

Tags: python, pandas, input

I have a module on a .py file that I am uploading using imp.
Once I upload the module, I would like to pass a dataframe from the jupyter notebook I am in, into the module using the function input().
Unfortunately, it seems that it does not recognize the input as a dataframe and does not load the dataframe data. 
When I try this on a separate notebook using a function, the process works just fine.

This is what I want to use:

```
Module = imp.load_source('Module', 'module.py')
mod = Module()
mod.load_default()
```

load_default is something like this:

```
def load_default():
    while True:
        try:
            req_item_path = input("ENTER info : ")
            # Added this:
            try:
                req_item_path = int(req_item_path)
                req_item = pd.DataFrame([req_item_path], columns = ['name'])
                break
            except:

                path_check = os.path.exists(req_item_path)
                if path_check == True:
                    try:
                        req_item = pd.read_csv(req_item_path)
                    except:
                        req_item = pd.read_excel(req_item_path)
                    break
                if path_check != True:
                    try:
                        isinstance(eval(req_item_path), pd.DataFrame)
                        req_item = eval(req_item_path)
                        break
                    except:
                           print("File does not exist or path is wrong. Please try again.")  
        except ValueError:
               print("File does not exist or path is wrong. Please try again.")    
    return req_item
```

It works as a single function, but when added inside the module it does not load the dataframe

Comment: Is load_default_files supposed to be equivalent to load_default?

Comment: Yes, I fixed it in the question